# Date format in difference using DateTime and date inside MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I'm working in some datatables for a ticket system that have SLA's, the ticket database is under MySQL

The SLA's are that the ticket must be solved within 45 min otherwise a warning label appears next to the ticket number

I'm using this method:

```
    $start_date = new DateTime(''.$rows->created_time.'');
    $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime("now"));
    
    $project_id_td .= '<a href="'.$href.'">CITA-'.$project_id.'</a>';
    if ($since_start->i > 45) 
    {
    $project_id_td .= '<span class="label label-danger pull-right">Incumpliendo</span>';
    }
```

Only works if establish the flag with days ($since_start->d > 1), but minutes or hours it gives me random numbers

I assume the problem is caused by the date formats

In the database the dates are like this:

```
2020-10-25 13:46:49
```

Is there a way to put DateTime and my database dates in the same format to do the proper difference?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `''.$rows->created_time.''`  what's up with the unnecessary string concatenation?

Comment: The problem is that the [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.dateinterval.php) properties (except for `days`) don't represent total time in the selected unit. It's more like _"1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, etc"_

Answer (score 3):

You could do the computation directly in the database:

```
select t.*, (created_time + interval 45 minute <= now()) is_sla_met
from mytable t
```

This adds another column to the resultset, called `is_sla_met`, that is set to `1` if the current datetime is less than 45 minutes after the `created_time` of the ticket, else `0`.